# How do I include custom command declarations in Pandocs YAML header?

Tags: pandoc

I would like to declare a custom command in Pandocs YAML header like so:

```
---                                                                      
title: Materials and methods
author: Marius Hintsche
header-includes:
   - \newcommand{\marius}[1]{{\color{green} #1}}
---
```

However, I get the following error, which goes away when I remove `#1` in the `\newcommand`.

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup
                                             \egroup \UL@putbox

error.
```

As far as I understood # should be a valid YAML character, so it should not need to be escaped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#` is the comment character in YAML, right? So what happens is the rest of the line gets commented out, and the group isn't closed because TeX never sees the `}}`, hence your error. Check the Pandocs documentation for how to handle this, I'm not sure what you need to do

Comment: I think inside a string the `#` character is interpreted as a literal (similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739639/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-a-multi-line-string-in-yaml) question)

Comment: That answer suggests that it depends on your YAML parser... If I put your YAML into an online parser, it reads that as a comment: [link](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=title%3A+Materials+and+methods%0Aauthor%3A+Marius+Hintsche%0Aheader-includes%3A%0A+++-+%5Cnewcommand%7B%5Cmarius%7D%5B1%5D%7B%7B%5Ccolor%7Bgreen%7D+%231%7D%7D&type=json)

Comment: Okay, then how do I escape this correctly? I tried putting the whole entry in single and double quotes, but this did not work either.

Comment: The question you linked to has a hint: use the pipe (`|`) character at the end of the `description:` line, and delete the dash on the next line: [link](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=title%3A+Materials+and+methods%0Aauthor%3A+Marius+Hintsche%0Aheader-includes%3A+%7C%0A++++%5Cnewcommand%7B%5Cmarius%7D%5B1%5D%7B%7B%5Ccolor%7Bgreen%7D+%231%7D%7D&type=json)

Comment: Or this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22483116/2449192

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `|` or `>` because I need this entry to be a list where on the next line other things are specified.

Comment: Then you need to ask the folks at Pandoc how to manage that, unfortunately, I think this question is off-topic for this StackExchange, since it is about Pandoc and not TeX and Friends. Best of luck!

Comment: @Marius: can you not do `header-includes: \n
  - >\n
       \newcommand{\marius}[1]{{\color{green} #1}}\n
  - \otherstuff`? That seems to work for me (note there's an indent on the 3rd line... can't format this properly in a comment). Also, I think this is q great question, perfectly on-topic for this site, and it should be re-opened.